# Runge-Kutta method for an ODE with initial value which is root of denominator

Tags: ode, numerics, runge-kutta, differential-equations

I wrote a code in Fortran to solve this differential equation using RK4 method:

$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=A\sqrt{\frac{B}{y}+\frac{C}{y^2}}
$$

$A$, $B$, and $C$ are some known constants. The problem is that my initial values are $x=0$ and $y=0$ and because $y=0$ is the root of denominator I get a run-time error.

Does anybody know how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not well posed. Multiply both sides by $|y|$ to obtain the ODE in the form
$$
  |y(x)| y'(x) = A \sqrt{By(x)+C}.
$$
If your initial condition is $y(0)=0$, then at the initial time you have
$$
  0 y'(0) = A\sqrt{C}.
$$
This means that if $A\sqrt{C}\neq 0$, no value of $y'(0)$ can satisfy the equation.

In other words, your problem is not that you don't know how to convince whatever ODE integrator you are using to accept your initial condition. Your problem is that your mathematical model makes no sense.

Comment: Not necessarily, if at the origin $y \sim \sqrt{x}$ then $y y'$ has a finite limit at the origin. In fact, $y=\sqrt{x}$ is a solution for this ODE, for A=1/2, B=0, and C=1.

Comment: @MaximUmansky -- true, but is the solution unique? The right hand side is not Lipschitz, and so in general it may not be. As a matter of fact, $y(x)=0$ is also a solution for the same set of coefficients. Non-uniqueness still makes the problem ill-posed as well.

Comment: @ Wolfgang Bangerth Why is $y(x)=0$ a solution here? The left-hand side is zero while the right-hand side is infinity, that does not look right. Perhaps what you mean is $x=0$ for $\forall y$. But that cannot be a solution either because it is not a function.

Comment: Ups, sorry. I meant for $C=0$. For $C=0$, another solution is $y(x)\propto x^p$ with $p=3/2$.

Comment: @ Wolfgang Bangerth Yes, for C=0 there is an analytic solution $x^p$ but $p=2/3$, probably that's what you meant. Still, I don't see non-uniqueness of solutions, with y(0)=0 initial conditions, for given A,B,C.

Comment: @MaximUmansky Plugging $x^p$ into the ODE yields $x^{p(p-1)} \propto \sqrt{x^p} = x^{p/2}$ which has as solution $p=3/2$ and $p=0$. If you choose $A\sqrt{B}=3/2$, then both $y(x)=x^{3/2}$ and $y(x)=0$ are solutions with the same initial condition $y(0)=0$.

Comment: @  Wolfgang Bangerth Sorry I have to point this out, but when you multiply two powers of x, in this case $x^p$ and $x^{p-1}$, the exponents are added, not multiplied.

Comment: @MaximUmansky oh, doh! I suppose my mathematician's license will now be revoked :-(

Comment: So then, though, $y(x)=x^{2/3}$ and $y(x)=0$ are both still solutions for $y(0)=0$.

Comment: No, since it is a linear rather than a quadratic equation for $p$ there is only one solution. And it is clear that $y(x)=0$ cannot be a solution to the $original$ ODE because it makes LHS zero and RHS infinity.

Comment: $y(x)=0$ happens not to follow from plugging $x^p$ into the equation, but it's still a solution. Whether it is a solution to the *original* ODE as you point out is a question that one could argue about for a while. It is true that it's not a solution to the ODE stated in the original post, but one can suspect that that equation was derived in some way and then brought into standard form $y'(x)=f(x,y(t))$. The transformation to get it into standard form may be responsible for the loss of that solution.

Comment: (That's like when you derive the PDEs that govern mechanical steady states, you minimize energy which leads to a variational problem that have solutions in Sobolev spaces. But if you convert that into the strong form PDE we typically write down, these weak solutions are not always also strong solutions. But we nonetheless generally consider the weak solution a solution of the PDE in those cases.)

Comment: If we are not discussing now the actual ODE in the original question as stated, but some other ODE it is hypothetically related to then I just give up, cannot argue anymore

Comment: @MaximUmansky We continue to talk about the same ODE, just in different forms. You will probably agree that whether we write $-\Delta u=f$ or $(\nabla u,\nabla v)=(f,v) \; \forall v$, it's the same equation. We just have different connotations, but we're thinking of the same thing. Similarly, whether you write it as $mx''(t)=F(x(x),t)$ or $x''(t)=F(x,t)/m$, it's the same thing -- except the former may have solutions the latter doesn't if $m=m(x'(t))$ as is the case in relativistic mechanics. In those cases, we have to go back to asking what form the ODE originally had.

Answer (score 1):

The integration curves have the overall form as shown in the figure below,
[image] they have vertical asymptotes at $y=0$, which certainly creates difficulties for a numerical solver integrating from $y=0$ (x does not matter). This does not necessarily mean the problem is ill posed; that would be the case if the integration curves diverge rapidly as the initial condition is varied, i.e., lack of stability in the sense of Lyapunov. But for the ODE in hand, a simple fix is to step away by a small $\epsilon$ above $y=0$ and integrate from there, the integration curve will stay close to the exact one.

Comment: A more elengant possibility (in the case the ODE is well posed): use an implicit scheme. In this way, you don't evaluate the function in its singularity.

Comment: Yes, an implicit solver would also be an option to avoid the problem with initial conditions. Of course an implicit solver would also have some tolerance $\epsilon$ hidden in it, but this approach does look more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

If the constants are positive then $y$ is positive and setting $u=y^2$ you get $$u'=2A\sqrt{B\sqrt{|u|}+C}$$ which is a little more regular and allows the initial value $u(0)=0$ without singularity.

This equation is still stiff close to the initial point, which should have consequences for the local error with fixed-step RK4 as long as $u$ is close to zero. One could counter-act this by using smaller step sizes initially.